# Comparing C strings vs. string pointers for equality

Tags: c, shell, input, command-line-arguments

So I am working on a project to create and use a shell. One thing that must be done is "|executable| -p |prompt| should allow the user to select an user-defined prompt. Otherwise, the default should be “257sh> ”. I wrote my code to do this however no matter what it keeps moving into the else statement. After some experimenting I know that my `argv[1] == "-p"` line is what is causing the issue, because without it the code works. The thing is that when I print out argv[1], it prints "-p" (assuming thats what I input). Here is my shell function.

```
    void shellLoop(char *n)
{
    char *line;
    char **args;
    int status;
    char name = n;

    do{
        printf("%s>", n);
        line = sysReadLine();
        args = splitLine(line);
        status = execute(args);

        free(line);
        free(args);
    }while(status);
}
```

And here is my main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc == 3 && argv[1] == "-p"){
        shellLoop(argv[2]);
    }
    else{
        shellLoop("257sh");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `argv[1] == "-p"` : use `strcmp` instead of `==` in C.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `argv[1] == "-p"` you compare two *pointers*, and two pointers that will never be the same.

To compare strings in C you use the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function: `strcmp(argv[1], "-p") == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use strncmp(char *str1,char *str2,int n) to compare the first n bytes of two strings.

Comment: "Also" implies the method shown actually works - which it does not. And as both strings are guaranteed to be `nul`-terminated, `strncpy` is not necessary.